# How to convert a pandas datetime column into a timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name                            Application              Last used    
 Administrator                     app1          2019-02-19T09:20:00+01:00  
 Administrator                     app2          2019-02-19T09:20:00+01:00  
 Administrator                     app3          2019-02-19T09:20:00+01:00  
 Administrator                     app4          2019-02-19T09:20:00+01:00
```

I wanna convert the last used to a timestamp of integers, but can't find a solution for this

I tried:

```
df['Last used'].astype(np.int64)//10**9
```

this gave the following error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2019-02-19T09:20:00+01:00'

Comment: Do you mean convert it from a string type column to a datetime type column? If so, you can use pandas `to_datetime()` function. Otherwise, please show a desired output for this sample data

Comment: I mean these timestamps for example: 1349720105, 1349806505, 1349892905, 1349979305

Comment: Still is unclear! How did you convert from your `last used` column into `1349720105`?

Comment: My guess is OP want the number of seconds since epoch: `df['Last used'].astype(np.int64)//10**9`

Comment: This were random values from someone else code, to be clear i want to convert datetime values to integer values

Comment: I tried that, but that gave the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2019-02-19T09:20:00+01:00'

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Last used']).astype(np.int64)//10**9`

Comment: right off the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#from-timestamps-to-epoch

`(stamps - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')`